# Two date dimension with different date to load fact table

Tags: talend

I am new to Data warehousing and have set up multiple Dimension Tables and Fact Tables using a STAR schema AND USE TALEND.

I have a question that I have 2 date dimension. In dimension table1 a format date is `yyyy-mm-dd` and THE SECOND date_dimension the format is `dd/mm/yyyy`. I would to join two table to load my fact table.

Comment: With Talend, all your date types will be treated as JAVA date type, then the pattern of your data won't matter in the treatment.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are stored as "date" type in your data store, you can select "date" data type in Talend (in the diagram of t *** input component that you use to retrieve data). This way, your date will be recovered as a java Date object that don't care about display format. This way, the comparison of the 2 dates will work as expected.

If, however, the dates are stored as text (varchar for example), you'll have to retrieve them in "String" data type in Talend. After, you'll have to use a tConvertType component to convert the data type from string to date. Both t***Input will need a tConvertType with a different date pattern.

See the documentation for tConvertType : https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide62EN/tConvertType

Comment: but when i tried to tjoin this two date and use TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",row2.DATE_DU_JOUR)

Comment: i get the error: you row2 can not be resolved a variable